# Inject something to ASP MVC Result

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

In my project I need to add functionality, that show infobox in right top corner of page, when  client save something. Everything works fine when save operation do redirect to another page in my solution.

Client run save action:

```
[SaveAction] //my own action filter to show info box
public ActionResult Details(int id, FormCollection form)
{
    var pojazd = PojazdRepo.GetById(id);;
    if (UpdateAndSave(pojazd, form))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(GetDetailsViewModel(id, true));
    }
}
```

Now my action filter test that `ModelState.IsValid` is true then add something to TempData:

```
public class SaveActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private bool test;
    private bool isAjax;

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext ctx)
    {
        test = ctx.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid;
        isAjax = ctx.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
        base.OnActionExecuted(ctx);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext ctx)
    {

        if (test)
        {
            if (isAjax) ctx.Controller.TempData["ActionPopUp"] = "";
            else ctx.Controller.TempData["ActionPopUp"] = "save";
        }   
        base.OnResultExecuting(ctx);
    }
}
```

And my Site.Master run script if `TempData["ActionPopUp"] = "save"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var test = '<%: TempData["ActionPopUp"] %>';
        if (test != '') SaveSuccessPopUp(test);
    });
</script>
```

As mentioned, this solution works fine, when controller make Redirect and Site.Master is loaded again, my problem is, how to inject SaveSuccessPopUp() function to action result, when Action was called by AJAX and return something, what don't reload page and don't run Site.Master `$(document).ready` code block.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

You need to probably work with **partial view** here. I mean if your request is an ajax request, append the `TempData` again and the `TempData` will be outputted inside the **partial view**.

How will you send that partial view output as chunk of html?

I have a blog post about how you can send the partial view as string. The topic is different but you will get the idea:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views

Here is an example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult toogleIsDone(int itemId) {

        //Getting the item according to itemId param
        var model = _entities.ToDoTBs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ToDoItemID == itemId);
        //toggling the IsDone property
        model.IsDone = !model.IsDone;

        //Making the change on the db and saving
        ObjectStateEntry osmEntry = _entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(model);
        osmEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
        _entities.SaveChanges();

        var updatedModel = _entities.ToDoTBs;

        //returning the new template as json result
        return Json(new { data = this.RenderPartialViewToString("_ToDoDBListPartial", updatedModel) });
    }
```

`RenderPartialViewToString` is a controller extension. you can find the the complete code for that from below link:

https://bitbucket.org/tugberk/tugberkug.mvc/src/6cc3d3d64721/TugberkUg.MVC/Helpers/ControllerExtensions.cs

After you have your html back on the client side code, append it you DOM and work on it. Animate it, show/hide it, do whatever you need with it

Comment: I thought about it to call this popup function in partial views or javascript callbacks that are performed in Ajax queries. But this entails searching and modifying large number of places in the code (this application is quite extensive :( )
And this is the reason why at least the normal queries require only adding to the action attribute.

Comment: @PiotrStyczyński I see but if you think about it, you will see that there is no other option. You are not rendering your Layout (Master) page when you make an ajax call. So, you need to figure out to it on your client side code.

Comment: In public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext ctx) function, you have access to Result of action call, maeby there is option to incect there JavaScriptResult with call of my popup JS function?